# Enqueue script based on ACF value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I wanted to see if this is possible and how I might be able to solve this - But here is what I am using:

I have one ACF group created, that has two fields:

- Enable OneTrust, name: enable_onetrust, Radio Button
- Script Tag, name: onetrust_script_tag, Text Area

When I add in the `<script>` tag provided by OneTrust, it auto enqueues and renders on the front-end and build out the Object, so I am not calling `wp_enqueue_script` on it at all in the `functions.php` file.

Here is the setup in the UI:
[image]

What I want to do is create a conditional, that when `enable_onetrust` is set to no/false, don't enqueue the script, otherwise enqueue it.

Since the script isn't being called using `wp_enqueue_script` anywhere, how do we go about doing this?

Comment: What is your code to enqueue the script?

Comment: It doesn't have a code to enqueue the script at all, what happens is that it reads the `<script>` tag from the database and it builds out the Object from OneTrust automatically. If I comment out the script inside the ACF Text Area, the OneTrust Object goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the field value of you enable OneTrust field.
I would use a true/false field for that.

If you have a true/false field you can do this:

```
<?php 
function my_assets() {

    $enable_onetrust = get_field('enable_onetrust'); 

    if ( $enable_onetrust == true ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'onetrust', 'PATH-TO-JS', , false, true );
    }
    endif;

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
  
?>
```

And for the other script you can use something like this:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    $enable_onetrust = get_field('enable_onetrust'); 

    if ( $enable_onetrust == true ) : ?>     

        <script>
            // Your Script
        </script>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php }, 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Cray, this is super helpful! I will test this out now and double check, it would have been much easier if I had a direct path to the `PATH-TO-JS`, but once I add in the `<script>` inside the ACF Text Field, OneTrust Object gets built on the front-end automatically, but this is super helpful!

Comment: How gets the OneTrust Object built on the front-end automatically? Or do you mean the name of the JS file?

Comment: You can add all code in the second function if you want

Comment: Yeah let me test that out, if the `<script>` tag is added by OneTrust in the header, I can hook into `wp_head` right? Or is there another specific?

Comment: yes, you can change it to `wp_head`

Comment: Can you `wp_enqueue_script` using scripts loaded from ACF? Looks like the scripts that are saved in `onetrust_script_tag` ACF Text Field, are being loaded from a CDN.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about that :-(